# Shifting a single nibble in Java BigInteger?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have a Java BigInteger containing two bytes (ex: 1000000100110111).  I would like to shift only a single nibble, the right-most nibble in the left byte (in bold below) to the left by one bit:

1000 **0001** 00110111

Making the result after the shift:

1000 **0010** 00110111

Any thoughts on the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: [Logical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) [non-circular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_shift)?

Comment: @Shahzeb - Well, they're 16 _bits_, but it's unclear whether the most significant bit is supposed to be the sign bit or not.  So, he may not be able to store them in a `short`, but he could in an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to shift a single bit, you should rather clear the old and set the new:

```
bigint.clearBit(n-1)
      .setBit(n)
```

If you want to shift those next to four most left bits, you could bitmap them out, shift them, and then or them back:

```
bigint.and(0xf0ff).or(bigint.and(0x0f00).shiftLeft(1))
```

Or for clarity:

```
unshifted = bigint.and(0xf0ff);
shifted = bigint.and(0x0f00).shiftLeft(1);
result = unshifted.or(shifted);
```

If you don't want 1100 1111 to become 1101 1110 (notice the spill), you can apply the bitmap again on the shifted, before the or.

Comment: Presumably that's just an example.  What if it's 0111?  I *think* he would want 1110.

Comment: Right, I was just mentioning that he could save some operations if he knew that the bitstring was very sparse.